# Add a user entity to the session storage attribute for easy access

Tags: wakanda

is it ok to use the sessions storage to store a user entity on login so that it is easy accessible everywhere with `sessionStorage.myUser`

example:

```
userObject = {
    ID: myUser.ID,
    name: myUser.username,
    fullName: myUser.fullName,
    belongsTo: ["User"],
    storage: {
        myUser: myUser // wakanda entity
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sessionStorage` object can only store simple elements (Int, String, JSON, Boolean, Array)

If the ID of the user in the directory is different that the ID of the same user in the DB, You can store the later on the storage and use it to access the user entity later on. Since the user entity will be already in the cache, this will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do that, you could take all the data from the entity that you need, and add it to the `storage` property of the session object. For example here is how I store user data in storage that I grab from the entity

```
var userEntity = ds.TableName.find("fieldName = :1", fieldValue);`

var putIntoStorage = {myEmail: userEntity.email, myAddress: userEntity.address};`

userObject = {
    ID: myUser.ID,
    name: myUser.username,
    fullName: myUser.fullName,
    belongsTo: ["User"],
    storage: putIntoStorage
};
```

For example,
`currentSession().storage.myEmail;` run on the serverside will return the email that you grabbed from the entity and put into the object that you store in `storage`. If you have questions about this let me know.